# The harmonic conjugate of $\Im e^{z^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

It is obvious that $e^{z^2}$ is analytic, right? So the harmonic conjugate of $\Im e^{z^2}$ is $\Re e^{z^2}$, isnt' it?

However, the solutions manual I'm consulting gives the answer as $\Im (-ie^{z^2})$, which is not the same function, and I don't understand.

Comment: If $w=a+bi$ then $\Re w=a$ and $\Im w=b$, furthermore $-iw=b-ai$ so $\Re(-iw)=b=\Im(w)$ and $\Im(-iw)=\Re(w)$. In particular if $w=e^{z^2}$ then $\Im(-ie^{z^2})=\Re(e^{z^2})$; they are the same function.

Comment: Isn't the imaginary part of -iw equal to -a instead? I.e. equal to the **negative** of the real part of w ??

Comment: Yes, you're right, there is a stray negative sign, what in the world am I thinking? It looks like the solutions manual has the negative of the correct answer; it's possible their definition of "harmonic conjugate" is loosened to "harmonic function with orthogonal gradient," but then conjugates are no longer unique and this is not a standard definition. Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real-valued functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$, we say that $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$ if $u+iv$ is analytic. This is **not** a symmetric relation between $u$ and $v$. For example, $e^x\sin y$ is a harmonic conjugate of $e^x\cos y$ because $e^x\cos y+ie^x\sin y=e^z$ is analytic, but $e^x\cos y$ is **not** a harmonic conjugate of $e^x\sin y$ because $e^x\sin y+ie^x\cos y$ is **not** analytic (check the Cauchy-Riemann equations).

If $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$, meaning that the function $f(z)=u+iv$ is analytic, then $-if(z)=v-iu$, being a constant multiple of $f(z)$, is also analytic; this shows that $-u$ is a harmonic conjugate of $v$, **in other words**, $-\Re f(z)$ is a harmonic conjugate of $\Im f(z)$.

To repeat one more time: although $\Im f(z)$ is a harmonic conjugate of $\Re f(z)$ (assuming $f(z)$ is analytic), it's $-\Re f(z)$, **not** $\Re f(z)$, that is a harmonic conjugate of $\Im f(z)$. This is true for any analytic function $f(z)$, including your problem function $f(z)=e^{z^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this answer my question? I've been given u, and I found its harmonic conjugate to be v, but the official solution gives the harmonic conjugate of u to be -v. My question: is there is an error somewhere?

Comment: THANKS!!  I've finally got it (well 80%). One more question: "f is a harmonic conjugate of g" NECESSARILY means that g is the real part of the analytic function, correct?  That sentence CANNOT mean that g is the imaginary part, right?

Comment: Thanks again so very much. (I deliberately didn't want to use u and v because I did not want the symbols to convey whether they are the real or the imaginary parts, thus obscuring my very question.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $w = a + bi$. Note that $\text{Im } (iw) = \text{Im } (-b + ai) = a = \text{Re } (w)$.

So yes, it is the same function up to a minus sign, which I don't know where it comes from - perhaps it comes from the manual's specific definition of a harmonic conjugate.

Comment: Thanks, but are you saying that If v is the harmonic conjugate of u, then -v is also a harmonic conjugate of u? That doesn't feel correct.  (Also, I note that you haven't shown that Im (**-iw**) equals Re (w) at all.)